# Getting DbSet<MyTable> from a string

Tags: entity-framework

ADO.NET user trying EF for the first time. I'm trying to get a table from a string of the table name..
Harder than I presumed. 
Basiclly I'm here:

```
var tableName = "Name.Entities.Measure" + measureType;
var table = Activator.CreateInstance("Name.Entities", tableName);
var unwrapped = table.Unwrap();
var type = unwrapped.GetType();
var dbset = context.Set<type>();
```

OR

```
switch (tableString)
{
    case "table1":
    return GetDataFromTable1();
    case "table2":
    return GetDataFromTable2();
}
```

Less code would be nice ;)

Thinking of making an extension method with a searchable collection of all the entities.
Better solution anyone?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this. Such a method could not return a strongly typed result (i.e., you'd get, say, `IQueryable` rather than `IQueryable<T>`. What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @CraigStuntz There are several tables in the db, and javascript returns returns a string saying which to use. This is a service btw. In ADO.NET this is simple to solve.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing. Try the non-generic version of Set():

```
var tableName = "Name.Entities.Measure" + measureType;
var type = Type.GetType(tableName);
var dbset = Context.Set(type);
```

Comment: Thanx, but that didn't help, haven't got the entity type. Only a string that is the name of the entity type.
So either a horrible switch, or ADO.NET, that's the options I know of.

Comment: Don't you have the type? Change var type = unwrapped.GetType();
var dbset = context.Set<type>(); to var dbset = context.Set(type);

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem. Try the following:             var tableName = "Name.Entities.Measure" + measureType;
            var type = Type.GetType(tableName);
            var dbset = Context.Set(type);