# how to dynamically change the dbset in entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have a query that should be run on difference sets, how can i change dbset in query for each type

my try:

```
    using (TestContext rpContext = new TestContext(connectionString))
        {
            IEnumerable<TargetType> query = null;
            dynamic TargetSet = null;

            switch (basicDefinitionType)
            {
                case MyEnumType.MySet:
                    TargetSet = Convert.ChangeType(TargetSet, typeof(DbSet<MySet>));
                    TargetSet = rpContext.MySet;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("can not detect type");
            }

            var q = from r in TargetSet
                    where (nodeId == null ? r.ParentId == null : r.ParentId == nodeId)
                    orderby r.Code
                    select r;
            query = (IEnumerable<TargetType>)q.ToFullyLoaded();

            return query;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not to use `context.Set<Type>()` it will return DbSet per type, you may also want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376975/getting-dbsetmytable-from-a-string

Comment: tnx, dude, i read your link

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DbSet](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbsetclass.aspx) as csharpfolk mentioned, but this could be a case where the [repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) could make your code more readable and maintainable. Internally, the repository pattern should make use of the DbSet but it abstracts that from the code that consumes it.

Comment: hmm, i think i should make a generic function to get repositories, and now i just write a generic function `GetChildrenBaseQuery<T>` that use `rpContext.Set<T>()` in implementation that i use it in my cases `query = GetChildrenBaseQuery<MySet>(rpContext, nodeId);` but i think about some think like my failed trying. because i have a function and same query for 27 tables

Comment: my code works well at all, but its just was a  question and a new try