# Net Core: Add to DbSet<Table> from a String Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I Get Entity Framework Core DBSet, where the input is a string variable name? Attempting to get DBSet Type below, however receiving IQueryable instead.

This previous answer is not working in Net Core 3.0

Resource: [Getting DbSet<MyTable> from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376975/getting-dbsetmytable-from-a-string)

[How do I select correct DbSet in DbContext based on table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305737/how-do-i-select-correct-dbset-in-dbcontext-based-on-table-name)

```
var tableString = "Product";
var tableType = Type.GetType(tableString, false, true);
if (tableType == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid table type: {tableType }.");
}

_dbContext.Set<Product>().Add({ProductId = 5, ProductName = "Furniture"});  // Adding to a DbSet, This will work !

_dbContext.Set(tableType).Add({ProductId = 5, ProductName = "Furniture"});  // Cannot add to this,  since this is actually an IQueryable
```

> Error: 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a method in the DbContext get the DbSet from type or a string in .NET Core 3.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?view=efcore-3.0

As a work-around, you could try this,

```
var dbSet = (DbSet<Product>)_dbContext.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(tableType).Invoke(_dbContext, null);
```

Comment: hi, you are still using <Product> hard coded in the answer so it will not work (DbSet<Product>)_dbContext.GetType

Comment: Yeah, true. So how are you going to create a Product without hard-coding? If the answer is using reflection to create the product dynamically, why can't you just use the Add method on DbContext?

Comment: "product" is input as a variable string, can only be seen in that way

Answer (score 0):

first, you need a Extensions

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyProject.Utils
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static object Set(this DbContext _context, Type t)
        {
            return _context.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(_context, null);
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can try this code.

```cs
var tableName = "UserInfo";
string tableFullName = $"Qc.Data.Domain.{tableName}";
string domainAssembly = "Qc.Data";
string assemblyQualifiedName = Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(domainAssembly, tableFullName);
var entityType = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName);

using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    var dbSet = dbContext.Set(entityType);

    var entityJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        Avatar = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png",
        Gender = UserGender.Man,
        NickName = "UserName",
        UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
    });

    var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(entityJson, entityType);


    var methods = dbSet.GetType().GetMethods();

    MethodInfo AddMethod = dbSet.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Add" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 1);

    object retVal = AddMethod.Invoke(dbSet, new object[] { model });

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

i tried two hours , hope can help for you.

Comment: hi all we needed is this, and it works thanks !  feel free to test and edit your answer           var entityJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
            var model = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(entityJson, tableType);

Comment: you can use AutoMapper also. convert object to your DB entity ,If it helps you , pls click up arrow, thanks.

Comment: I just added the simplified changes which worked for me, deserialize and serialize, feel free to try it out